# Where to put .htaccess file in Easyphp?

Tags: .htaccess, easyphp

Sorry if this is a basic question but cant find the answer anywhere

when using easyphp (on localhost), where do you put the htaccess file?

if the answer is "at the root level" - what does that mean; at the root of the alias? or www root? or in the system config folder?

please help
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put your `.htaccess` in the root directory of your web application.

For example, if the `.htaccess` content is relevant to your site "mysite" whose path in your filesystem is `.../www/mysite`, you must put your `.htaccess` in `.../www/mysite`.

Comment: thanks, but what exactly does that mean? which folder?

Comment: @Lan I've added an example ;)

Comment: thanks, also, is there a way to debug it when testing? to see where its actually trying to redirect to, (if its not working)? thanks

Comment: @Lan There is a `RewriteLog` option that can be set with the path of the log file for url rewriting in your `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`.